# What is the recommended way to shrink/stretch shapes in Android + OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I've been having fun with Android and OpenGL in a little side project meant to learn about it, but now I want to implement some animations and I'm having trouble getting information on how to proceed.

Let's say I have a square with a texture on it. Let's say I want to create it very small, and then gradually stretch it to its normal size. Only that square can be subjected to the effect and nothing else around it. I have this assumption that building a new vertex buffer every time is expensive, and for the animation to be fluid, this would need to happen very frequently. Is that the norm or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stretch/scale objects you should use matrices, not recreating vertices.

You can read a tutorial here http://www.learnopengles.com/understanding-opengls-matrices/ or google for another one, there are lots of educational materials on OpenGL ES 2.0.